# Compute Engine - Trace issue

Tags: google-compute-engine

By following steps given in  below link I enabled tracing for compute engine. 
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-trace/cloud-trace-quickstart
After enabling trace, it seems to automatically get disabled. I have tried many time but same result. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Cloud Trace only traces Google App Engine, so it might not be helpful to you if you are using Google Compute Engine.

Try making sure you have an App Engine app deployed and that you have billing enabled.